# Linux command to move a directory into another directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, mv

I have a directory dir1 and it contains a lot of files and directories and also I have another directory dir2 and it is empty. And I need a linux command to move the dir1 with all the files and folders into dir2. The result should be like that dir2/dir1/...

I found the mv command, but it moves a file from a directory to another directory and I don't want that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv` command can move directories also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use cp with -r to copy content along with the folder recursively

```html
 cp -r dir1 dir2/
```

Then remove the folder if u want (double check if u copied all the files LOL before removing)

```html
 rm -r dir1
```